# webscraping in python for Knowledge

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am just trying to scrape a website to get the title and product description etc just for practice, i have grabbed the product name but i am confused how to grab the following things.

In here I am just trying to grab the product title and its description.
i have grabbed the title successfully.

```
from requests_html import HTML,HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card')
containers =  r.html.find('.item-container',first=True)
#print(containers.html)
title = containers.find('.item-branding img',first=True).attrs['title']
#print(title)
description = containers.find('.item-title',first=True).html
print(description)
```

But the problem is from description i want to grab the data which is inside this `a` tag inside the `i` which shows the description of product i can't do so any help would be appreciated

From this:

```html
<a class="item-title" href="https://www.newegg.com/evga-geforce-rtx-2080-ti-11g-p4-2281-kr/p/N82E16814487418?Item=N82E16814487418" title="View Details"><i class="icon-premier icon-premier-xsm"/>EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 11G-P4-2281-KR BLACK EDITION GAMING Video Card, Dual HDB Fans &amp; RGB LED</a>
```

I want to grab this:

```
EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 11G-P4-2281-KR BLACK EDITION GAMING Video Card, Dual HDB Fans &amp; RGB LED
```

Comment: Basically something like `the_link.text`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [BeautifulSoup][1] in order to **scrape** the content of this website, your code should look like this:

```
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

containers = soup.find("div", {"class","item-container"})
title = containers.findAll("img", {"class":"lazy-img"})[1]["title"]
description = containers.find("a",{"class":"item-title"}).getText()
print(description)
```

hope this helps
[1]: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/